# Could a Research Library SE be useful?

Tags: discussion

I created a proposal in Area 51 for a research library type of site. Just thought I'd tell you since I've done some here and also ask if you think you could benefit from it.

[Research Library Proposal - Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48790/research-library?referrer=qfyY-JC7d58N5QfMOt5KEg2)

Comment: No question asked. This seems to belong to chat. Closed as off-topic.

Comment: Basically I'm wondering whether a SE like that would be useful to yous here.

Comment: You may want to ask this [on the discussion pages of Area51](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Maybe you better start such a Research Library site outside the SE network since it may not fit into SE (?).